# c# time calculations

Tags: c#, time

Does someone knows how to calculate the total hours between 2 times?
For example if a worker clocks in at 8:00 and out at 16:00, I would like to know that in decimal it's 8.0 hours and it's 8:00 hours.

I'm using C# framework 2.0.
The variables that hold the in and out time are of type string.

TY

Comment: Which timezone are you using? It matters because if it is a local timezone that observes daylight saving time then the solution will be a bit more complex.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
        DateTime start = new DateTime(2010, 8, 25, 8, 0, 0);
        DateTime end = new DateTime(2010, 8, 25, 16, 0, 0);
        Console.WriteLine((end - start).TotalHours);
```

for strings:

```
        DateTime start = DateTime.Parse("8:00");
        DateTime end = DateTime.Parse("16:00");
        Console.WriteLine((end - start).TotalHours);
```

Comment: +1 for using the subtraction operator overload; it's much more intuitive. It should be worth noting that the subtraction of two `DateTime`s will return a `TimeSpan`.

Comment: +1 only solution that is using strings. Well reading an answer completely and not just the title is a skill.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this daylight saving time safe method. The function is correct for both UTC and local timezones. If the `DateTimeKind` is `Unspecified` on either of the inputs then the return value is undefined (which is a fancy way of saying it could be incorrect).

```
private double TotalHours(DateTime earliest, DateTime latest)
{
    earliest = (earliest.Kind == DateTimeKind.Local) ? earliest.ToUniversalTime() : earliest;
    latest = (latest.Kind == DateTimeKind.Local) ? latest.ToUniversalTime() : latest;
    return (latest - earliest).TotalHours;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by subtracting two datetimes and using the `TotalHours` property of the resulting `Timespan`. Heres an example:

```
    DateTime start = new DateTime(2010, 8, 25, 8, 0, 0);
    DateTime end = new DateTime(2010, 8, 25, 16, 0, 0);
    int hours = end.Subtract(start).TotalHours;
```

Comment: this is wrong. Hours return hour part of time, not total hours

Answer (score 0):

```
System.DateTime punchIn = new System.DateTime(2010, 8, 25, 8, 0, 0);

System.DateTime punchOut = new System.DateTime(2010, 8, 25, 16, 0, 0);

System.TimeSpan diffResult = punchOut.Subtract(punchIn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out [`TimeSpan.TotalHours`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalhours.aspx):

```
TimeSpan difference = datetime2 - datetime1;
double totalHours = difference.TotalHours;
```